# grep and not equal to in an if condition

Tags: ruby

I want to check if "Listen 8581' is present in the `check` variable. If it is *not*, I want to add 'Listen 8581'.

I have this code:

```
if (found = check.grep(/Listen 8581/)).empty?
  run "#{try_sudo} sed -i '$ a\Listen 8581\n' #{ports_file}"
  puts "OOOps".red
end
```

Comment: `grep` works on an enumerable object, like an Array, and is somewhat like `select`. We can't tell if `check` in your code is a scalar/string and you're trying to write Perl code in Ruby, or actually using `grep` as it's meant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
unless /Listen 8581/.match check
  # run your code here
end
```

Comment: I'd write the test like `check[/Listen 8581/]`.

Answer (score 1):

As a stylistic thing, assigning to a variable inside a conditional is a bad idea, because it's an easy opening for bugs and maintenance issues. When debugging a big program it's easy to miss the logic or a missing `==`. Assign first then check for clarity:

```
found = check.grep(/Listen 8581/)
if found.empty?
  run "#{try_sudo} sed -i '$ a\Listen 8581\n' #{ports_file}"
  puts "OOOps".red
end
```

I know it's tempting to avoid adding one variable on the stack, but if your code is embedded inside a method that extra variable will fall out of scope and it'll be a moot concern.

It's idiomatic in some languages, such as Perl and C, to write that way, but it's something that I've seen cause problems many times in my career and something I avoid as a result.

Comment: ok, i use a vraible nw. But still doing with megas coding, Thanks a lot.

Comment: That's fine. Add my recommended change to his code using `check[/Listen 8581/]` and you'll be on your way to writing "Zen-like" code, which is what we try to do in Ruby.